# Set Zoom in a PowerPoint document window without activation

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am creating a PPT from an Excel-VBA file and want to set the zoom of the ppt to 100%.

How can I do this from the Excel file without activating the PowerPoint window?
Or how can I even do it with activating the window?

The following example code in excel opens a ppt file on the Desktop and tries to set the zoom of this ppt but it seems not to work:

```
Sub CreatePptAndSetZoom()
    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim strTemplate$

    'Look for existing instance of PPT
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Create new instance of PPT if no instance exists
    If ppApp Is Nothing Then Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    'Define Path of Template and open new ppt
    strTemplate = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Test.pptx"
    Set ppPres = ppApp.presentations.Open(strTemplate, False, True, True)

    'Set Zoom
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom = 100

End Sub
```

Setting the Zoom from the Excel file in the Excel file works with the slightly different statement (without `View`):

```
Application.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem without any code in the ppt file?

Answer (score 2):

With some help (Thank you R3uK!) I found the following solution based on the last code in the question:

**Solution:**

Instead of `ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom = 100` use the following:

`ppPres.Windows(1).Panes(2).Activate`     --> Activate the main slide pane 
   `ppPres.Windows(1).View.Zoom = 100`       --> Set the zoom of the active pane in the window

**Some remarks:**

`ppPres.Windows(1)` -> Collection with only the window where the presentation is shown in

`ppApp.Windows(1)` -> Collection with all opened ppt windows. So if a ppt was opened before item 1 this would not return the right window.

`ppPres.Windows(1).Panes(2)` -> Collection of panes inside of the ppt window which are in my case the following ViewTypes dependent from the item number:

Item 1: `ppViewThumbnails` (miniature slides on the left)
Item 2: `ppViewSlide` (main view)
Item 3: `ppViewNotesPage` (comment section on the bottom)

So in my example I wanted to change the zoom of Item 2 the main slide view pane.

Answer (score 1):

Your code run smoothly using late biding :

```
Sub ZoomInPptFromExcel()
    Dim ppApp As Object

    'Get existing instance of PPT
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Set Zoom
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom = 100

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub CreatePptAndSetZoom()
    Dim ppApp As Object 'PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As Object 'PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim strTemplate$

    'Look for existing instance of PPT
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Create new instance of PPT if no instance exists
    If ppApp Is Nothing Then Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    'Define Path of Template and open new ppt
    strTemplate = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Test.pptx"
    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(strTemplate, False, True, True)
    'Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add

    'Set Zoom
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom = 100
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think this has nothing to do with late or early binding. When I open a new ppt and then run the code it works with both, late and early binding. It seems that both codes do only fail with an automation error when I try to set the zoom of my VBA-created ppt file.

Comment: @JackTheFruit : Is the app visible? Please edit your post to provide your full code so that we can see what you are doing.

Comment: @JackTheFruit : I've edited my post to include a working version of your code, I also tested it with `Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add` and both case works nicely for me.

Comment: Thank you for the update. But sadly it did not work for me. The creation of a new file `Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add` and setting the zoom afterwards worked thought. But when I try to open an existing file and try to set the zoom afterwards I get an automation error. I also tried different folders of the template, and standard parameters for th open method. I do not have any idea how to proceed with problem solving... Sorry. Accidentally send this comment too early.

Comment: @JackTheFruit : could you be accurate please? Tell me what went wrong, so that I can understand and try to find a solution.

Comment: Sorry. I send the comment before too early by mistake but edited it while you already have requested detailed info...

Comment: @JackTheFruit : On which line do you get the Automation Error? Did you try Late Biding (`Dim ... As Object`), because it solved my automation error. Changing folders won't change that error.

Comment: I get the error on the `View.Zoom` line. I tried to print out the zoom and it returned 34 instead of the 60% shown in the ppt window. Aaand now i see what is the issue here: The `ActiveWindow` is in my case the left part in ppt where there is the miniature slide view... So selecting the first shape on the first slide `ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Select` and then setting the zoom would solve the problem. But I have no good feeling with selecting things... The remaining question would be if there is another way to access the right documentWindow?

Comment: @JackTheFruit : You can try `ppApp.Windows("Test.pptx").View` or `ppApp.DocumentWindows("Test.pptx").View`

Comment: I tried and it did not work. I think you have to address Items of the windows collection with its item number. Thanks for all your help @R3uK I think I found a solution.